# TelephonyManager.getLine1Number dont return nothing

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have a app made for android, this uses the TelephonyManager for get the Line number

```
((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getLine1Number()
```

I have the correct permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

The work fine in my Galaxy Ace but in my Galaxy SIII i get nothing. can help with this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the SIM card.

I have the same problem. You should check if you can get the number, if not, ask the user for it ;)